# What do they mean when they say Unity generates fragmentation in Linux?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

Since the news about Ubuntu 18.04 LTS leaving Unity to return to Gnome3 I've read in many places that this will help reduce fragmentation in Linux?
What exactly do they mean?

Comment: I'd love to see a lengthy discussion on this but in all honesty I think its too broad and VTC. +1 though :)